# Application using TailwindCSS cannot change to light mode if system is set to dark mode

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, t3

I am working on a new project using the T3 stack, and I want to be able to toggle from light and dark mode. However, only the text colour changes, and the background is always set to the system's preferences.

If I set the browser theme to light, then the background is light, and if I set the browser theme to dark, then the background is dark. While either is set, I toggle light and dark theme within the Web app and the text colour changes, but the background remains the same.

Is there a specific class I need to set to some element, other than what is described in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode), in order for the theme to properly switch between light and dark?

In other words, are `bg-base-100` and `bg-base-content`, etc. CSS classes that are dynamically set to the proper colours, or do I have to explicitly set the colours of every elements in my app?

#### Edit

This is a representation side-by-side between Google Chrome (left) and Firefox (right) of the exact same site. The background changes because I have added `bg-slate-100 text-slate-800 dark:bg-slate-800 dark:text-slate-100` to the content container element.

Note how the toolbar (i.e. `navbar bg-neutral text-neutral-content`) and the table (i.e. `table table-compact`) do not change background color, but the text color is correctly applied.

[image: Light mode]
[image: Dark mode]

Comment: Need to see code (where both text and background presents) plus config file. There are no restrictions - you may appoint your own element to be a parent selector for all of your content. By default dark mode is set to media, so it expects `dark` class to be present on `html` attr, but it can be any logic - JS based, media prefers or like here - [I've created](https://play.tailwindcss.com/OUvnnMa2g5?file=config) simple switcher based on CSS `:has()` selector. The point of it is to demonstrate you're in charge how to customize dark mode, but you need to use `dark:` variant (or custom one)

Comment: I do not know how to reproduce this. But I get what you wrote about how to implement changing theme using `darkMode: "class"` in the config. In fact, that's not the issue; I see some text elements changing colors, but the page default background does not. I have to manually set the bg and text colors. So, I am wondering if this is the expected behavior, of if Tailwind should have default bg colors according whether dark mode is set.

Comment: Tailwind doesn't have default "dark" colors but [some preflight stylings](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight). So every color should have its dark alternative on your own with `dark:` variant. Like `bg-yellow-500 dark:bg-red-500` - yellow on light, red on dark - there are no dark fallback for yellow color. So if your custom `bg-base-100` comes alone (without dark-pair) - it will remain same color as on light theme. If you set dark variant pair but it's keeping ignore it - this is unexpected. Again cannot say without seeing some code

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka I updated the question with comparative browsers showing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My theme switching function was like the one found [in the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode), that is :

```
function applyTheme() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (
      localStorage.theme === "dark" ||
      (!("theme" in localStorage) &&
        window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches)
    ) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am using DaisyUI, so I missed [this part](https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/) :

```
<html data-theme="cupcake"></html>
```

In other words, the `data-theme` HTML attribute. Modifying my `applyTheme` function to :

```
function applyTheme() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (
      localStorage.theme === "dark" ||
      (!("theme" in localStorage) &&
        window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches)
    ) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
      document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
      document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
    }
  }
}
```

Makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a button in your UI with a click event listener that adds or removes a `dark` class to your components.

sample code :

```
// On page load or when changing themes, best to add inline in `head` to 

avoid FOUC
if (localStorage.theme === 'dark' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
} else {
  document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
}

// Whenever the user explicitly chooses light mode
localStorage.theme = 'light'

// Whenever the user explicitly chooses dark mode
localStorage.theme = 'dark'

// Whenever the user explicitly chooses to respect the OS preference
localStorage.removeItem('theme')
```

documentation link : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode

Comment: Yes, I have that. But changing from "light" to "dark" does not change the value of `bg-base-100` and the like.

Comment: do you use `dark:bg-base-100` ?

Comment: Yup. Background is "white" in dark mode just the same.